# cannot call to a function to imported library in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

> TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_crunker___default.a.fetchAudio
>   is not a function[Learn More]

My code is like below:

```js
import Aplayer from 'vue-aplayer';

import Crunker from 'crunker';

Crunker.fetchAudio('a.mp3','as.mp3');
```

I surely do have a function called `fetchAudio()` inside `crunker` modules.I cannot access it by importing..
I am new to `vuejs` so is there something wrong with the way to import libraries?

Comment: Initialize it. `let audio = new Crunker(); audio.fetchAudio(....)`

Comment: yeah i forgot to mention that i had tried that too. it gives similar error like  **TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_crunker___default.a is not a constructor[Learn More]**